# "python.bat is not recognized" where to get python.bat?

Tags: python, batch-file, chromium-embedded

I have python.exe installed on my machine (several times) but no python.bat.  I'm trying to build Chromium Embedded Frameworks and the master batch file says

```
@echo off
python.bat tools\gclient_hook.py
```

but python.bat not on my machine giving error `'python.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Is there a python scripting edition or something?
UPDATE: [SO User R-nar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5323213/r-nar) was correct, needed stripping off .bat

This is not my code but part of Chromium Embedded Frameworks.
 [cef_create_projects.bat](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/f8909fe9e01ab40eae4b65bf3ac73c8d5fae464e/cef_create_projects.bat?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Ok, so after fixing I am running into Python 2 errors.  It looks like python.bat may have been an indirection mechanism to keep the Python 2 scripts working.

Comment: you should just be calling `python`, not `python.bat`

Comment: it's probably a script calling a hardcoded python file somewhere in your server, avoiding to set the path properly.

Comment: Most probably, no. there's no such _edition_. It's a custom `.bat` which is probably calling a python executable

Comment: removing the .bat will make you execute python.exe instead. I guess `python.bat` will be just to decide if executing `python2.exe` or `python3.exe` based on some checks.

Comment: @Sembel: ah!  Tell me more, running into Python 2/3 issues subsequently!

Comment: For what I see you are suppposed to also have Depot Tools  https://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools

Comment: After running gclient open a command prompt and type where python and confirm that the depot_tools **python.bat** comes ahead of any copies of python.exe. Failing to ensure this can lead to overbuilding when using gn - see crbug.com/611087

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki   I will try this.  Thanks for expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use python.bat from depot_tools, see step 2 here:

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart#markdown-header-windows-setup

> 2. Download depot_tools.zip and extract to "c:\code\depot_tools". Do not use drag-n-drop or copy-n-paste extract from Explorer, this will
>      not extract the hidden ".git" folder which is necessary for
>      depot_tools to auto-update itself. You can use "Extract all..." from
>      the context menu though. 7-zip is also a good tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if have the the directory of python.bat in your environment path variable, otherwise python.bat must me in the current working directory.

Comment: R Nar got the right answer in stripping off .bat.  I dunno why it was there in the source in first place (this is not my code).